# C++ Executable Freezes at Runtime

Tags: c++, runtime, freeze, codeblocks

I wrote a simple console program for the use of testing some key classes in a library I'm building. Now, the code builds correctly with no errors. But, after executing the code, I found that the application stops working after calling the Index method at a certain point in the code. I tried debugging a few different ways to get more information about the problem, but the information I gathered didn't help me at all. Maybe it will help someone else who knows what I'm not doing(or doing incorrectly).

Here's the contents of the Util namespace;

```
    template<typename var>
class VectorNode
{
    public:
    VectorNode(var value, VectorNode<var>* next = NULL, VectorNode<var>* prev = NULL)
    {
        data = value;
        t_next = next;
        t_prev = prev;
    }
    ~VectorNode()
    {
        if (t_next != NULL)
            delete t_next;
    }


    virtual VectorNode<var>* Next(){ return t_next; } // get the next node in line
    virtual void Next(VectorNode<var>* newNode){ t_next = newNode; } // set the next node in line

    virtual VectorNode<var>* Prev(){ return t_prev; }// get the previous node in line
    virtual void Prev(VectorNode<var>* newNode){ t_prev = newNode; } // set the previous node in line

    virtual var Value(){ return data; } // get the node's value

    private:
    var data;
    VectorNode<var>* t_next;
    VectorNode<var>* t_prev;
};

template<typename var>
class Vector
{
    public:
    Vector()
    {
        tailNode = new VectorNode<var>(*(new var));
        headNode = new VectorNode<var>(*(new var), tailNode);
        tailNode->Prev(headNode);
        size = new int;
        *size = 0;
    }
    ~Vector()
    {
        delete headNode;
        delete size;
    }


    int Size(){ return *size; } // get the size of a vector
    void Add(var toAdd, int index = 0) // 
    {
        VectorNode<var>* lastNode;
        if (index > (*size))
            index = *size;
        if (index < 1) // add to the end of the vector
        {
            lastNode = tailNode;
        }
        else
        {
            int i;
            if (index <= (*size / 2)) // if the index is less than half the size, iterate forwards
            {
                lastNode = headNode;
                for (i = 1; i <= index; i++){ lastNode = lastNode->Next(); }
            }
            else // otherwise, iterate backwards
            {
                lastNode = tailNode;
                for (i = *size; i >= index; i--){ lastNode = lastNode->Prev(); }
            }
        }
        VectorNode<var>* temp = lastNode->Prev();
        VectorNode<var>* newNode = new VectorNode<var>(toAdd, lastNode, temp);
        lastNode->Prev(newNode);
        temp->Next(newNode);
        *size = *size + 1;
    }
    void Remove(int index) // remove an index
    {
        VectorNode<var>* toRemove;
        VectorNode<var>* lastNode;
        int i;
        if ((index > *size) || (index < 1)) // if not in the domain...
            index = *size;
        if (index <= (*size / 2)) // iterate forwards
        {
            lastNode = headNode;
            for (i = 1; i < index+2; i++){ lastNode = lastNode->Next(); }
        }
        else // iterate backwards
        {
            lastNode = tailNode;
            for (i = *size; i > index; i--){ lastNode = lastNode->Prev(); }
        }
        toRemove = lastNode->Prev();
        VectorNode<var>* temp = toRemove->Prev();
        temp->Next(lastNode);
        lastNode->Prev(temp);
        delete toRemove;
        *size = *size - 1;
    }
    var Index(int index) // get the value of a node
    {
        VectorNode<var>* lastNode;
        int i;
        if (index <= (*size / 2)) // iterate forwards
        {
            lastNode = headNode;
            for (i = 1; i <= index; i++){ lastNode = lastNode->Next(); }
        }
        else // iterate backwards
        {
            lastNode = tailNode;
            for (i = *size; i >= index; i--){ lastNode = lastNode->Prev();}
        }
        return lastNode->Value();
    }

    private:
    int* size;
    VectorNode<var>* tailNode; // the head and tail nodes are placeholders, to keep the list inside its boundaries
    VectorNode<var>* headNode;
};
```

If you don't feel like reading that, I marked each method with a comment, explaining its overall purpose. Also, I tried adding a small explanation of some of my blocks of code.

And, here's the entry function, and inclusions;

`#include "iostream"`

```
#include "stdlib.h" // this has nothing in it that's being used
```

```
#include "testhead.h" // the location of the Util namespace
```

int main()
{
    using namespace Util;

```
Vector<int>* x = new Vector<int>();
x->Add(42);
x->Add(24);
x->Add(12);
x->Add(21);
std::cout << "Listing Indices\n";
for (int i = 1; i <= x->Size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << i << "\t" << x->Index(i) << "\n";
}
std::cout << "Size(pre-removal):\t" << x->Size() << "\n";
x->Remove(2);
std::cout << "Size(post-removal):\t" << x->Size() << "\n";
std::cout << "Listing Indices\n";
std::cout << 3 << "\t" << x->Index(3) << "\n";
for (int i = 1; i <= x->Size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << i << "\t" << x->Index(i) << "\n";
}
system("Pause");
```

}

Okay, the results I got where this. Before using the Remove method, any index can be accessed from the Vector class freely. But, after using the remove method, no matter what index is removed, no index above one can be accessed. Except, in the case which we remove the first index, then no indices can be accessed. I tried stepping through the code, but it brought me up to this line of code in the index method;

```
else
{
lastNode = tailNode;
for (i = *size; i >= index; i--){ lastNode = lastNode->Prev();} // error occurs after running this line
}
```

Now, since I was able to figure out the Remove method was causing the problem, I went back and got some output about that. I had it run the following line prior to finishing its execution, twice. Once before toRemove is deleted, and once again after it is deleted.

```
std::cout << (lastNode->Prev() == temp) << "\t" << (temp->Next() == lastNode) << "\n";
```

Before it is removed, it prints 1 twice, indicating the comparison was true. But, the second time I call either the Prev and Next method, and the program freezes. I know this is because I freed the place in memory, but the comparison shows that any references from other nodes to the node I removed were gone. Now, my specific question is why exactly this is being caused, and how can I fix it? I know a little bit about managing memory on the heap, and this doesn't exactly appear as though it would cause any issues with the program. So, I could use a short explanation as to why this happens if anyone would be kind enough to provide it.

If it's any assistance, I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE and the GNU GCC compiler. Also, please tell me if I'm doing something wrong related to the way I asked my quetsion. I don't visit Stack Overflow often, and I don't ask questions here. This is just the best place to have your questions answered that I am aware of.

Comment: Did you try stepping through with a debugger?  Or adding trace statements?

Comment: People are going to see Vector and make assumptions it is the standard one.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor of the VectorNode class deletes the object pointer to by the t_next pointer. Calling delete on the toRemove pointer means that the destructor of that VectorNode object gets called, and then the next one, and then the next one etc. etc.

So basically, when you delete toRemove, you delete toRemove and all the objects that come after this. This causes the tailNode's t_prev to point to memory that you have already freed, and you then try dereferencing those pointers in your Index function, and that's not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a `VectorNode` that has its `t_next` member pointing to some other node, the destructor of `VectorNode` will delete that other node (which in turn might go on to delete further nodes).

When you remove a node from the middle of a list with `Remove()`, the `t_next` of this node will point to the further nodes of the list. When this node is deleted, the destructor will also delete all the nodes following it in the list. Continuing to use this half-deleted list it will result in all kinds of problems.

Other random observations:

- Why is `size` a `int*` instead of a normal `int` or `size_t`? I can't see any reason why this should be a pointer.
- `new VectorNode<var>(*(new var))` should really be `new VectorNode<var>(var())` to not unnecessarily leak memory.
- The `t_next != NULL` test before `delete` is unnecessary
- Are you planning to create classes deriving from `VectorNode<>`? If not, than there is no reason why the methods would need to be `virtual`.
- Using 1-based indexing in `Add()` is unusual, one would expect zero-based indexing

Also I feel obliged to tell you that there are standard library containers like [`std::list<>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) and [`std::vector<>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) which implement this kind of structures.

Answer (score 1):

Calling remove deletes a node, but deleting a node deletes all the nodes->next

```
~VectorNode()
{
    if (t_next != NULL)
        delete t_next;
}
```

so deleting element 2 of your 1 based vector kills all the other elements as you have experienced, and there is no longer an element 3 to investigate